# How to delete rows in tables that contain foreign keys to other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, delete-row

How to delete row in table that contain foreign keys to other tables but I don't want that the row in other table deletes, so I cant make use of CASCADE?

How  can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET NULL` instead of `CASCADE`.

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  I just never thought of trying it, because its obviously impossible.

Comment: it shows me this error: [Err] 1005 - Can't create table '.\rts\#sql-22c_49.frm' (errno: 121)

Answer (score 0):

If table has foreigh key it means that it is a child table; in this case you can delete rows with DELETE statement, parent table won't be modified.

Comment: oh no! i want delete row from parent table, no child! i want when i delete parent nothing happen to child .